# Does an aerial respond to any frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism

what is the range of frequencies that will produce a signal in an aerial?

would  a frequncy of 1 Hz be effective with appropriate power? and what about an upper limit, do frequncies in the region of visible light or x-rays produce an oscillation of charges in an aerial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antennas receive electromagnetic radiation by the electrons in the antenna interacting with the electric field of the incoming wave and generating a detectable current.

This is a table of [electromagnetic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation):

[image: emr]

As long as the wavelength of the radiation is large, the antenna will respond to the fields , so some signal will be there. For visible light ( the small colored band on the left, go to [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Interactions_as_a_function_of_frequency) to read the legend) the wavelengths are small, of the order of atomic distances, and as we know light scatters off metals or is absorbed and it heats them. No antenna function, i.e. current, can build up, and the same is true for smaller wavelengths.

For higher wavelengths, where waves can be modulated and carry a signal, there  is [frequency dependence](http://aerialsandtv.com/polardiagrams.html#XB14ApolarDiagram).

Comment: But people are working on nano-antennas for photovoltaics. Also, sometimes photosynthesis is described in terms of antennas. A new subject, I do not know much about it.

Comment: there was a US patent granted years ago for a silicon-based nanoarray of dipoles intended to behave as antennae for light, converting it directly into electricity- or so reads the patent. But there is no way to build it, let alone rectify the AC into DC and so forth. For now we'll just have to leave that work to photosynthetic organisms.

Comment: @Pieter. I do not know the patent. In all that use you mentioned antenna is used in a figurative sense. In pv no AC current is induce by the light. PV materials are not metals. PV is based upon fighting vs the heating mentioned in the answer. The underlying mechanism is different. Antenna, in pv as in photosynth, means receiver of merely energy, not of a signal.

Comment: @Alchimista In nanoantennas, the materials are shaped like rods and sometimes like dipole antennas. The connections that are made with antenna theory are not just superficial. People are working on transmitters and on receivers.  But evidently, there do not exist PEC - Perfect Electrical Conductors - at these wavelengths.

Comment: @Pieter. Ok !. Nanoantenna ==> nanometers. Then they indeed antennas . Got your point. However we shall be aware of the broad sense of the word in pv and ps. Nice point that at this scale no perfect conductors exist. I would say is evident but I never thought about.